# ValueError: libcublas.so.*[0-9] not found in the system path

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, cublas

I'm trying to import and use ultralytics library in my Django rest framework project, I use poetry as my dependency manager, I installed ultralytics using `poetry add ultralytics` and on trying to import the library in my code I recieve this error

```
ValueError: libcublas.so.*[0-9] not found in the system path [my project and virtual environment paths]
```

how can I solve that?

Answer (score 62):

Update: this issue was fixed in PyTorch 2.1.1.

Since May 9 2023 there is an [open issue with PyTorch 2.0.1 and 2.1.0](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/100974) causing `poetry lock` to delete libcublas from `poetry.lock`. Their wheel contains the dependency, but their PyPi upload did not get it.

A workaround would be to skip these versions in pyproject.toml (typically under `[tool.poetry.dependencies]`):

```
torch = ">=2.0.0, !=2.0.1, !=2.1.0"
```

Make sure to run the following to correctly update your poetry env after making the change

```
poetry lock --no-update
poetry install
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to install cuda on your system.

E.g. on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-cuda-toolkit-gcc
```

Comment: sorry but the bug persists under poetry, even if installed

Comment: Then pls try the pytorch downgrade as described above

Answer (score 1):

If you come here and have this problem with some other library while using poetry, try to install it directly in `.venv`. For me that was:

```
   pip3 install "transformers[torch]"
```

Answer (score 0):

according to this response :

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/100974#issuecomment-1541856571

you can also install the nvidia-* dependencies specifically,
in your poetry venv / pyproject.toml

Answer (score 0):

add this to pyproject.toml

`torch = ">=2.0.0, !=2.0.1, !=2.1.0"`

`poetry install`

THIS WORKS

ok im not exactly sure how it works. I checked my history I'm still confused but when the correct version is selected you should see `poetry install` would install a bunch of nvidia libraries. after that when I run my script it works perfectly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

add this to pyproject.toml

`torch = ">=2.0.0, !=2.0.1, !=2.1.0"`

`poetry lock --no-update`

`poetry install`

Answer (score 0):

What caused the issue in my case was deleting .local folder where local library files are usually stored. I uninstalled `torch` and did a `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=12.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia` which removed the error and was the beginning of the solution.